# Jaxb : Append field of Request XML without modfying JAXB java class

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I am using JAXB 2.0 for the Application Deveopment which is using RestFul Webservices .
Now there is a modification in the request , that is i  will be getting another filed/variable in the request XML .

```
<Root Id="567" att="758" />
```

Modified Request will be

```
 <Root Id="567" att="758" anotherfiledadded ="kiran" />
```

My question is , is it possible to automatically append that field (anotherfiledadded)in the UserData class (Without modifying the UserData ??)

**The below is my UserData  class**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class UserData {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String Id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String att;

// getters and setters
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Would you be getting too many such "unknown" fields?

Comment: No , i will  gettting only one field .

Comment: Then why can't you just modify that class?

Comment: Where does the data for the additional attribute come from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834573/insert-logic-code-into-generated-jaxb-java-files-by-xsd-def , the link has solved your question.

Comment: reference link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834573/insert-logic-code-into-generated-jaxb-java-files-by-xsd-def  which has solved the problem in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the field at runtime with [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/). But... It looks like you would also require to add the Annotation *@XmlAttribute* and I don't know if **javassist** allows you to add annotations... Anyways give it a try.

See: [Javassist Add](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#add)

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSLT to apply an attribute into your XML document.  All of the classes below are available in the JDK/JRE since Java SE 6.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserData.class); 
JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, myUserData);

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource("addMyAttribute.xslt");
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer(xslt);
t.transform(source, result);
```

If you are implementing your RESTful service using JAX-RS you could plug-in this logic via a `MessageBodyWriter`: