# JAXB 2 Maven plugin - Force java source generation, to use collection for child?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have 2 complex types in a XSD file that I may not change. One has multiple children "filepath" occurrences and the other always has 1 "filepath" child.

JAXB generates either of these differently, one is put in a list of entities and the other is just the single JAXB entity.
This is a problem for me, as I want JAXB to give me 2 equal classes for the sake of inheritance. (I am using JAXB inheritance plugin)

Is there a way to make JAXB generate the filepaths child property of the "EntitySingleFile" complextype as a list, perhaps using JAXB bindings?

These are the XSD definitions:

```
<xs:element name="EntitySingleFile">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="filePaths" type="bgl:FilePaths" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and

```
<xs:element name="EntityMultiFile">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="filePaths" type="bgl:FilePaths" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This is what im currently getting from these XSD files:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "EntitySingleFile")
public class EntitySingleFile
    implements IDrawConfiguration
{
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = FilePaths.class)
    protected IFilePaths filePaths;
....
```

And for multifile:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "EntityMultiFile")
public class EntityMultiFile
    implements IDrawConfiguration
{
    @XmlElement(required = true, type = FilePaths.class)
    protected List<IFilePaths> filePaths;
```

Comment: I've removed the tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin tag since this has nothing to do with th `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably just need the collection method in order to implement a certain interface, I think the easiest would be to use something like the Code Injector plugin to generate an additional `getFilePaths()` method.

See these answers for the hinst on usage:

- [Inserting code with XJC+xsd+jxb using the options " -Xinject-code -extension "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262289/inserting-code-with-xjcxsdjxb-using-the-options-xinject-code-extension)
- [Insert Logic code into generated JAXB java files by XSD def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834573/insert-logic-code-into-generated-jaxb-java-files-by-xsd-def)

You'll probably also need `jaxb:property` customization to avoid naming collisions in getters, but I hope you see how it's solveable.