# How to append field or method to generated source code or insert field/ from bindigns JAXB file

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, code-generation, xjc

Is it possible for XJC to generate custom field/method to all generated classes from schema in .xsd ?

I've got ~1200 classes generated from xsd model. All of them has 2 versions - JAXB generated files for serializing /deserializing and entity files for data model.  Hyperjaxb3 generated entities with hjid for all entity. But for JAXB classes I need generated id's too, but i don't know how to do that? Is any option to generate it with xjc binding  or use some kind of source code procesor (like maven plugin) for appending fields with getters and setters to source code?

Answer (score 0):

- Use the [code injector plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834573/insert-logic-code-into-generated-jaxb-java-files-by-xsd-def) to add code.
- Write an own XJC plugin.