# Generate XML with attribute which is absent from the schema

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm generating OpenOffice XML using JAXB, and need to apply an `xml:space="preserve"` attribute to a `t` element.

```
    <r>
        <t>
            foo
        </t>
    </r>
```

Should be

```
    <r>
        <t xml:space="preserve">
            foo
        </t>
    </r>
```

I've used JAXB to generate Java classes from Open Office schemas. `<t>` type is represented as a String in the CTRElt Java class, so there is no way to set this attribute. When I unmarshall from an existing document and marshall, previously existing `space` attributes are no longer present.

The relevant portions of the schema are as follows:

`<xsd:element name="t" type="ST_Xstring" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Text</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:element>`

`<xsd:simpleType name="ST_Xstring">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Escaped String</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:simpleType>`

How can I generate XML which has this required `space` attribute? Modifying the schema is not an option. Do I need to customize JAXB?

Comment: You could potentially use an `XmlAdapter` to handle this use case.  The following article may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/xml-schema-to-java-generating.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, this lets you format the value in the tag, but I don't see a way to customize the tag element itself, by adding an attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jaxb : Append field of Request XML without modfying JAXB java class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827978/jaxb-append-field-of-request-xml-without-modfying-jaxb-java-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up generating the XML and using a regex to add the attribute :(